# thesis class doesn't work fine

Tags: languages, overleaf, thesis

I'm using the thesis class (https://ctan.org/pkg/thesis?lang=de) for my thesis in LaTex but I have some problems. Overleaf didn't know the thesis class so I had to load up the class by my self on the LaTex project.  Howsoever I have problems with the label of figures, tabels and the table of symbols (for which I'm using the useagepackage "listofsymbols").
I have for the defualt language of the whole file ngerman but the labels are in english ("Fig" instead of "Abb" e.g.). Furthermore the table of symbols isn't a "chapter" by his own (like the table of contents e.g.) - maybe the usepackage "listofsymbols" doesn't work with this class?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This package appears to have been last updated in 1995. Unless you have a compelling reason to employ it, trying to get it to work with an up-to-date LaTeX distribution may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you. Oh that's a little bit old. Do you have any recommendation which is suitable for a bachelor thesis?

Comment: In my experience, the only good reason for using a specific thesis-type package is if your university or organization compels you to use that package. If there's no such coercion, using a ready-made package to "handle" the formatting requirements almost invariably ends up making you spend lots of time fine-tuning the package's settings. You're probably better off working with a "standard" document class -- say, article or scrartcl -- and using 5 to 8 pertinent packags plus a couple of font packages if you don't use Computer Modern (the default font).

Comment: For an overview of frequently loaded LaTEX packages, do check out the posting [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553/5001) Which packages you should load for your thesis naturally very much depends on your field (about which you haven't said much so far).

Comment: Depending on the length of your thesis `article` or `report` might be a good choice. If you want/need more customisation options, you can try the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl` or `scrreprt`. `memoir` is another popular powerful document class. I'd stay away from everything that calls itself 'thesis class': Those are often heavily customised and can be tricky to modify. Sometimes they aren't maintained or supported any more. In this particular case the class is just outdated.

Comment: Thank you very much! I decided me for the report class and it works perfectly.