# A good graphics program?

Tags: graphics

Anyone can give me an advice on finding a good program that would allow me to make free-body diagrams, such as a pendulum, a block descending down an inclined plane, a spring attached to a block and other simple graphics. as the ones you see in a typical physics book. I am having difficulties finding such program. I know you may say Adobe Illustrator but that's too expensive and the learning curve is very high, at least for me. Thanks.

Comment: This looks off-topic to me as written. Can it be made more relevant to TeX? If not, then I'd be minded to close it.

Comment: Relevant to TeX, don't we have a big-list question about diagraming packages (TikZ, PSTricks, xy-pic, etc) somewhere?

Comment: @Matthew: do you mean this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205/86

Answer (score 5):

Your question is unrelated to TeX, but you may want to take a look at [the list of vector graphic editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vector_graphics_editors). For free mathematical drawing, I recommend [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/). For technical drawing, you will obviously need a [CAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design) program. A free alternative to Adobe Illustrator is [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) which could be used along with a [plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) to export to [PGF/TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ).

Answer (score 2):

As been stated before, the question is kinda unrelated to TeX, but I would recommend [Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_%28software%29) for almost any kind of "simple" figures. For example the *box-on-sloping-hill-with-spring* scenario.

Dia also has commandline options for export, ie very useful when using Makefiles :)

Comment: A shortcoming of Dia is the impossibility to use LaTeX markup — all special symbols get escaped. This can be disabled, but requires modifying Dia's source code (last time I checked).

Answer (score 1):

For the hard part, but keeping in line with TeX programs and consorts, you can take a look at [Metagraf](http://w3.mecanica.upm.es/metapost/metagraf.php) which provides a graphical frontend to [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).