# Use Parameter defined in PythonTex in Latex to open File

Tags: packages, python

I have a  Python code which detects my files. 
Now I will open it in Latex. But it seems not possible to give the detected names to Latex
I have tried this:

```
\begin{pycode}
l = [f for f in os.listdir('path') if f.endswith('.jpg')]
\end{pycode}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\py{l}}
```

Because it did not work I have used this:

```
\newcommand{\filename}{}
\edef\filename{l}

\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{\filename}
```

I need this because I have different files. They have filename that looks like this: part1_date, part1 is always the same only the date is variable. Therefore the day should be refered in the text (for example like the reference to a equation. And of course it must be printed.

Is it possble to do this with Pythontex? Or can I do this with another method?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I have no idea about `PythonTeX` but filenames with `_` characters are problematic, since `_` is interpreted as a math mode command starting subscripts.

Comment: Thanks, I can change the style of the filenames. What pattern would be ok and how can I create a read in routine and extract the filename in parts- it is not  important to use pythonTex,but it would be nice. I would prefer a method without  using shell escape.

Answer (score 2):

`\py` is not expandable. Therefore it cannot directly be used as file name for `\includegraphics`. But `\py` can be used to output TeX code that defines a macro. Then the macro contains the string and can be used for `\includegraphics`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
l = [f for f in os.listdir('../') if f.endswith('.jpg')]
\end{pycode}
\py{"\\def\\NumberOfFiles{" + "{}".format(len(l)) + "}"}
\providecommand*{\NumberOfFiles}{0}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\PrintFile}[1]{%
  \expandafter\PrintFileAux\expandafter{\number#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\PrintFileAux}[1]{%
  \py{"\\path{" + l[#1] + "}"}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\DefFileName}[1]{%
  \expandafter\DefFileNameAux\expandafter{\number#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\DefFileNameAux}[1]{%
  \py{"\\def\\FileName{" + l[#1] + "}"}%
  \providecommand*{\FileName}{}%
}

\tableofcontents

\section{\NumberOfFiles\ file\ifnum\NumberOfFiles>1 s\fi}

\multido{\i=0+1}{\NumberOfFiles}{%
  \subsection{\PrintFile{\i}}%
  \DefFileName{\i}%
  \ifx\FileName\empty
  \else
    \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{\FileName}%
  \fi
}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The current directory is `..`, because python is executed in the auxiliary directory `pythontex-files-<jobname>` (`<jobname>` is the name of the main LaTeX file without extension).
- If the path name contains special characters (such as `_`), then printing needs some more care. It can be printed as verbatim text. The example uses macro `\path` from package `url`.
- The loop over all files can be done in different ways. The example implements the loop in LaTeX using `\multido` of package `multido`.

  Alternatively the loop can be implemented in Python by calling a LaTeX macro with the file name and/or date as argument.
- The file name could be analyzed at TeX level to extract the date. The more comfortable way would be using Python to extract the date and convert it to the desired format.

Comment: Hi,
thanks a lot for your help. This works really great. I work with Latex since a few weeks and the options of latex are very impressive.

What would be better, making graphics in Matlab or in Latex by using pythontex?
Overlord

Comment: @Overlord: There are many, many ways and lots of programs to generate graphics. A starting point from the LaTeX side: [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205/16967)

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek thank you. At the moment  I work with networkX,matplotlib and pygraphviz. I use this for the additonal graphics. But the graphics which are the result of my research are my point of interest. The fastest way is to use matlab. The other one is using Latex. But I do not know if this make sense.