# Technical Drawing Using LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I wanted to draw this particular image in LaTeX but I don't know where to start:

[image: weanted]

I have no minimal working example I am just asking for directions please don't ridicule me.

Comment: Not to ridicule you but did you ever try a straight line in TikZ? Because there is not much else to do. And that you can find everywhere how. And that would be your MWE

Comment: two links with some physics examples

 - http://www.physagreg.fr/schemas-figures-physique-svg-tikz.php

- http://www.sciensass.net/TikZ.php

Comment: You can read about the wonder called PGF/TikZ here: https://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: You might also like to start with [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents).

Comment: Very bad quality. Of type "do this for me".

Comment: @Ingo If I ask for someone to complete what I am attempting to accomplish then you can tell me that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) solution that takes a different approach.

[image]

The shape is drawn as a very thick line and then the inside is erased.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
path s; s = ( (-1,1) -- (-1,-1) {dir -34} .. {dir 34} (1,-1) -- (1,1) ) scaled 1cm;
linecap := butt;
draw s withpen pencircle scaled 3pt;
draw s withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor background;
endfig;
end.
```

Here are some links for more information about Metapost

- [The Metapost page at TUG](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) is the best starting point.
- [The CTAN entry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/metapost) has the excellent introduction and the user manual.
- This [tutorial](http://www.ursoswald.ch/metapost/tutorial.html) has many useful examples.
- If you have any French, you might also enjoy [the Syracuse site](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/metapost/) and [Anthony Phan's pages](http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~phan/metapost.html).

I don't know of any technical drawing books that specifically deal with Metapost, but Knuth's own [Metafont book](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html) is very helpful for learning the core of the MP language (since it is more or less identical to Metafont).

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. Mind if i ask where can I read about this stuff? a book perhaps?

Comment: I'll update the answer with some references and links.

Answer (score 18):

And with [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[double,double distance=1.5mm]
  (0,0) --
  ++(0,-6cm)
  arc[start angle=210,end angle=330,radius=4cm] --
  ++(0,6cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. Mind if i ask where can I read about this stuff? a book perhaps?

Comment: @RicardoVelozJr You're welcome. For the powerful TikZ, you have the `PGF/TikZ` manual (`texdoc pgf` in a terminal, or in CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: @RicardoVelozJr If you want "to close" the walls you can add `line cap=round` or `line cap=rect` in the options of `draw` command. And if you want to "fill" the walls in yellow, for example, you can use `double=yellow` option.

Answer (score 7):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(4.46,5)
  % inner
  \psline(0.23,5)(0.23,1)
  \psarc(2.23,3){2.8284}{224.8}{315.2}
  \psline(4.23,5)(4.23,1)
  % outer
  \psline(0,5)(0,0.99)
  \psarc(2.23,3){3}{221.8}{318.2}
  \psline(4.46,5)(4.46,0.99)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that you can scale down the drawing using

> `\psset{unit = <a number less than 1>}`

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. Mind if i ask where can I read about this stuff? a book perhaps?

Comment: @RicardoVelozJr The user manual for PSTricks can be found at http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-user.pdf.