# Tool to draw diagram

Tags: diagrams

Please, I am writing a scientific paper and I use latex.
I have some figures to draw and insert it into the paper.
I would like to benefit from your experience. What tool I can use to draw my figures (diagrams) efficiently.

Thank you.
Best Regards.

Comment: Do you want to program the diagrams (TikZ, PSTricks, Metapost, Asymptote), or use a graphical interface to draw figures?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205/21344

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, graphical interface to draw figures.

Comment: An easy to use and advance graphical drawing program is [IPE7](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/). IPE is tightly integrated with LaTeX.