# How to use DIA?

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I'm new at Latex, and I'm trying to make a photo diagram.

And i have found the program "Dia" and wants to know how it works, i have tried to read the Manuel, but I'm not entirely sure of how it works, - So my questions is, how can i convert the Diagram to Latex, and then how do i include it in Latex?, And if i include a photo ind the diagram, where should i put the photo-file (in which folder)?

Comment: I had never heard of dia but google suggested a possibility but it's just a drawing program so asking how to use it is off topic for this site. pdflatex can input images in (for example) png format but it does not care how you made that image, just save your image in the same folder as your tex document.

Comment: According to the documentation you can export the diagram as a PDF file or even as PSTricks macros.

Comment: Exactly, I found out that the program have some abilities that i like to use. But my problem is, that i cant make it work,- I have to have more than two pictures beside each other, and some arrows between those

Comment: save your diagram as say `zzz.pdf` then a latex document of `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{zzz}\end{document}` should work. "can't make it work" isn't very specific, if you get an error ask a specific question and show the error message in full.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30368/5764)

Comment: Perfect, Thx a lot! -sorry I'm quite (what's it called - Yeah) Noob -.-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing package may have other facilities and be able to use other formats, but a basic use to get you started is:

Save your diagram as say `zzz.pdf` in the same folder as your latex document
then a latex document of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{zz‌​z}
\end{document}
```

should work.