# Which package can I use to draw this diagram?

Tags: diagrams

I wan to draw this digram below with latex which package can I use to draw it?

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPc6M.png)

Comment: -1: It's obvious that *any* of the graphics packages (`tikz` or `pstricks`) would be able to do this. And most likely a simple `picture` environment as well.

Comment: The arrows seem to correspond to pstricks'.

Comment: Very much related: [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205)