# Suggestions Request / App for drawing that code generate a tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf, inkscape

Do you know an application that I can use to draw diagrams or flowcharts or anything and then export a Tikz code for tex?

I downloaded "Tikzit" and it looks like I have to have a tikz file to open and edit, I tried to find ready shapes like rectangles or anything but it seems like they're not embedded.

I am now considering giving "geogebra" or "inkscape" a try.

If you know a straightforward application that I can use to draw blocks in and have it translate that into a tikz code, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You might look at the list of tools in the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents)

Comment: Why does it have to generate tikz code? I currently use IPE. You can insert Latex code in the drawing, then export it to pdf.  It works very well, and now I use it for all my diagrams. google IPE latex and you'll find it. It is easy to use.