# Smart Art flow diagram in latex?

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram, flowfram

is it possible to make a smart art like this in latx?:
The arrows dont have to be actually the same, but would be nice.

[image]

Comment: Of course this is possible. Most likely with TikZ. Please show us your attempts and we will be happy to help you on specific issues. The question, as it stands now, is no help for others and appears quite as a "do it for me" question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents)