# Functional programming diagrams of map, filter, reduce

Tags: diagrams, programming

I would like to create similar diagrams to these:
http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/graphics/small/map.gif
http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/graphics/small/reduction.gif

I am quite new to Latex. What package or tools should I use? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  The starting point is http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205/15925.  A common choice is to use the `tikz` package.    If have difficulty creating the picture(s), post your attempt and we will help.