# How can I create a graphic that depicts several layers of squares, with each square havingth a circle inside it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, matrices

I would like to create the following image in Latex. I have never used the graphical facilities before so I have no idea how I would go about doing this. The image is supposed to represent a crystal type structure with N layers and the dashes in the middle just mean there are arbitrary many layers in the middle. That's also why I have the three dots between L2 and LN on the right hand side.

So how can I create an image?

[image]

**Edit**
As suggested in the comments, here what I attempted before I posted here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}

\newcommand{\DrawNode}[2][]{%
\draw  [#1]
([shift={(-\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]#2.north east) -- 
([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]#2.north west) -- 
([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,+0.5\pgflinewidth)}]#2.south west) -- 
([shift={(-\pgflinewidth,+0.5\pgflinewidth)}]#2.south east)
;
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \node [draw=none, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm] (1) at (0,  0)  { };
   \DrawNode[dotted]{1}
  \node [draw=none, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm] (1) at (4,  0)  { };
   \DrawNode[dotted]{1}   
  \node [style={draw, draw opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm}] (2) at (2,0)  {  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could follow some of the suggestions in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents .  You will get more help here if you ask a specific question once you have made a start...

Comment: You could use a TikZ matrix of nodes (and add a MWE to your post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain something very similar *without* any graphic package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools, graphicx}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.2pt}
\newcommand\Bigcirc{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scalebox{2}{$\bigcirc$}}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!80!Lavender}[\arraycolsep][10pt]}c}

\begin{document}

\[ \renewcommand\arraystretch{2.4}%
\ADLnullwidehline
\nodashgapcolor
\begin{array}{C:*{5}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!80!Lavender}[\arraycolsep][10pt]}c:}>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!80!Lavender}}cc}%
\cline{1-7}
\rowcolor{white} \phantom{\bigcirc} & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \phantom{\bigcirc} & L₁\\
\cdashline{1-7}
\rowcolor{white} & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & & L₂\\
\dashgapcolor{Gainsboro!80!Lavender} \cdashline{1-7}%
& & & & & & & \multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{white}{$ ⋮ $}} \\
& & & & & & \\
\cdashline{1-7}
\rowcolor{white} & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & \Bigcirc & & L_N\\
\cline{1-7}
\end{array} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ..hmmm it appears very small when I generate a PDF containing it. I see arraystretch stretches the heights of the columns but how can I scale the widths?

Comment: The simplest would be to base the new column type on `p{somewidth}`, adjust `\arraystretch` and change the scaling of ``bigcirc`. For now, the squares are  more or less 8mm wide. Which  dimension would you like for the squares?

Comment: Ok I'd say that a scaling factor of 1.5 would be the ideal amount.

Comment: @sonicboom: I've updated the code with newparameters (actually I took 2 as a scaling factor,  as `1.5` wasn't very different from the result of the first code. Please see if it's fine.