# Please suggest some tools to draw a diagram with blocks?

Tags: graphs

I want to draw this image using latex code. Please help me 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried so far? This is no do-it-for-me-service, so please add a minimal code example of your attempts to clarify the question.

Comment: it seems that you like that some draw this image instead of you ... sorry, but site doesn't provide such a services. show us, what you try so far and we will help you where you will stuck in drawing. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: I agree with the above comments. I just want to add that you can use `tikz` and the basic commands are: 1) for rectangle:`\draw (X1,Y1)rectangle(X2,Y2);` where 1 and 2 are "diagonally opposite" corners  if you want it dashed try: `\draw[dashed]...` 2) for circle the command is `\draw[fill=black] (xcenter,yexnter) circle (0.3 cm)` where 0.3 cm is the radious. 3)For line: `\draw (x1,y1)--(x2,y2);`Also you can use `foreach` command to avoid repeating same commands. More help after MWE. (Just added the comment so you can give a try... I think there are better options)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents for suggestions

Comment: the point of a language like tikz is that it is text so you don't need a drawing tool just write it in whatever editor you use to write the rest of your document. If you want to draw that as an image in a drawing program, that's OK but then you don't need tikz, just save the image and include it into latex with `\includegraphics`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by defining a "pic" for each "block" of dots. You can read all about these in section 18.2 of the tikz manual (version 3.0.1a). Using pics, the MWE below produces the following diagram:

[image]

The idea of the MWE, which should get you started, is to define a pic `dotblock` that takes two arguments: a label for the block and the number of dots. You use this pic in several different ways, including

```
\pic at (0,0) {dotblock={a,2}};
\draw (0,0) pic{dotblock={a,2}};
```

These two commands are, I believe, equivalent.

The block of dots is drawn centered vertically from the point where it is placed. The point of giving the `dotblock` a label is that it gives an easy way to draw edges between the dots in the blocks using their coordinates: the command

```
\draw(a2)--(b3);
```

draws a line from the second dot in "block a" to the third dot in 
"block b".

Here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/dotblock/.style args = {#1,#2}{% #1=label, #2=number of dots
     code = {
       \foreach \adot [remember=\adot as \bdot,
                       evaluate=\adot as \y using 0.5-\adot+#2/2] in {1,...,#2} {
          \node[circle, fill=black, radius=1mm] (#1\adot) at (0.5,\y) {};
       }
       \draw[blue](0,-#2/2) rectangle (1,#2/2);
     }
   }
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) {dotblock={a,2}};
    \draw (2,0) pic{dotblock={b,3}};
    \pic at (4,0) {dotblock={c,1}};
    \draw[red, dashed, thin](-0.2,1.7) rectangle (5.2,-1.7);
    \pic at (7,0) {dotblock={d,1}};

    \draw(a1)--(b3)--(c1)--(d1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Given that the image in the OP has essentially three different types of repeating blocks I would actually define pics for each of them and then link them up. For example, the righthand block could be done with

```
 pics/twoBlock/.style args = {#1}{
   code = {
    \draw[dashed,green!80!black](0,0)--(6,0);
    \draw(0,0) pic{dotblock={{#1}1,2}};
    \draw(2,0) pic{dotblock={{#1}2,1}};
    \draw[thin,red,dashed] (-0.2,1.2) rectangle (3.2,-1.2);
    \draw(5,0) pic{dotblock={{#1}3,2}};
    \draw[thin,red,dashed] (4.8,1.2) rectangle (6.2,-1.2);
   }
  }
```

so that `\draw  (7,0) pic{twoBlock={A}};` would produce

[image]

The `twoBlock={A}`, and the definition of `twoBlock`, means that the dots in this diagram are labelled as `A11`, `A12`, `A21`, `A31` and `A32`. Notice that the green line is drawn first so that it is underneath the other objects in the picture.

Comment: Thanks for help, how to make dotted lines between the blocks

Comment: @new_born See the edit