# How to draw countour integration?

Tags: draw

I would like to know how can i draw this picture in latex, and what packages are needed?[image]

Thank your for your time.

Comment: Nothing too hard there.  Pick any of the drawing tools.  See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents

Comment: sorry  I dont have idea about how to draw that

Comment: There is tikz data visualization and pgfplots, or if you are fond of PostScript there is pstricks.  Read the manuals for tutorials.

Comment: I´ve been trying it, but I´m too inexperienced in this tools ;/

Comment: Could you help me with this picture, it´s too tricky ;/

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect but it should work!

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\varl{5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
      edgearrow/.style={draw=black,
                     postaction={decorate},
                     decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {
                         \arrow[black,scale=.6]{triangle 45}}}},
      edgearrow/.default=.55,
      line width = .5,
      every node/.style={scale=0.6},
      scale=.5]

%% Axis
\draw[edgearrow=.9] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw[edgearrow=.9] (0,0) -- (0,5);

%% Dashed square
\draw[dashed] (0,0)
-- ($\varl*(60:1)$) node[anchor=south]{$\ell\tau$}
-- ($(\varl,0)+\varl*(60:1)$) node[anchor=south]{$\ell\tau+\ell$}
-- (\varl,0) node[anchor=north]{$\ell$};

%% Graduation
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
  \draw (\x,.2) -- (\x,0) node[anchor=north]{$\x$};
}

%% Bullets
\fill (60:1) circle (.08) node[right=.1]{$\tau$};
\fill ($2*(60:1)$) circle (.08) node[right=.1]{$2\tau$};

%% Plain square
\begin{scope}[shift={(-1,-.6)}]
  \draw[edgearrow=.8] (0,0)
                   -- node[below=.05,pos=.8]{$\sigma^*$} (\varl,0);
  \draw[edgearrow=.8] (\varl,0)
                   -- node[left=.1,pos=.8]{$g$} ($(\varl,0)+\varl*(60:1)$);
  \draw[edgearrow] ($(\varl,0)+\varl*(60:1)$)
                   -- node[below=.05]{$\sigma^*$} ($\varl*(60:1)$);
  \draw[edgearrow=.3] ($\varl*(60:1)$)
                   -- node[left=.05,pos=.2]{$g^*$} (0,0);
\end{scope}     


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

By the way, I'm not sure that *TeX SX* is the place where you can just ask people to do the drawings for you...