# How to draw 2- and 3D geometrical figures?

Tags: diagrams

which software, tools, frameworks, packages ... could be used to produce figures like the ones below to include in LaTeX document.

[image]
[image]

Best regards

Comment: You can start with Tikz package.

Comment: ...or you can use ....https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: This is a more or less exact duplicate of this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205/15036