# Creating figures in latex for scientific papers

Tags: diagrams, figure-placement

I would like to ask if anyone has any experience creating figures in latex for scientific papers and would like to know what libraries are useful to achieve this. If latex cannot be used then what?

Comment: Hoi @ShaneGervais Welcome to TeX.

Comment: You are posing quite an open question about creating figures for scientific papers using a program designed to do just that. Can you be more specific in what kind of figures you want to make / use latex for?

Comment: See, if examples in https://texample.net//, https://pgfplots.net/ or https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery/Gallery sufficient scientific for you. Of course similar picture can be drawn by other packages too.  A lot of examples you can find here on site.

Comment: There is also a package - actually a document - showing all kind of uses of the `pgf` / `tikz` package at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/visualtikz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents)

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is quite general - and in a way a good question to summarise what is available out there - I share which packages I use making my papers. Mind you: apart from some general packages, there is also a personal preference in the choices involved.

**Bibliography**

1. `biblatex` and its recommended companion packages `csquotes` and `xpatch`. I use `Zotero` with the `Better BibTex` addon as reference software and export `.bib` libraries from there to be used in my `.tex` files

**Drawing (general)**

2. `TikZ / PGF` as it is a very versatile package in creating all kind of figures, plots and whatnot.
3. `pgfplots` as a specialised package to draw 2D/3D plots. It is based on `pgf`obviously.

**Drawing (chemistry specific)**

4. `endiagram` and `modiagram` are two packages also based on `pgf` that are specialised in drawing energy diagrams and molecular orbital diagrams respectively. To be used in chemistry related articles.
5. `chemfig` draws organic compound structures and again based on `pgf`
6. `chemmacros` used to print chemical formulas and projection figures like Newman. It also uses `pgf`, but has a few important (seperate) companion packages:
7. `chemformula` to typeset the formulas properly,
8. `chemgreek` to define a Greek character set to be used in `chemmacros`
9. `chemnum` to annotate structures and formulas so they can be used as reference labels.

There obviously are a lot more packages available depending on the scientific area you are working in. As I am involved in teaching - or better educating -  students in chemistry, my choices are based on that area.

There is an older question containing a list of packages used to create graphics. You can find that list here: [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents)

Comment: There is already [such a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents). Maybe it would be better, to extend that.

Comment: Thanks @cabohah did know of that list. Extending or better updating that list is an excellent idea. I will put that link in my answer so everyone coming across this question will be redirected to that list.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer