# Can't include a picture in pdf using \includegraphics command

Tags: graphics, eps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflate)

In `LaTeX` I used the package `\usepackage[driver]{graphicx}` and used `\includegraphics` command to include a `.eps` format picture. But the picture not shown in the pdf file.Is there any way to do this? Any suggestion will help me.

Comment: See [this answer to a more general question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflate/1075#1075)

Comment: Please do look at the suggested duplicate question.  If that _doesn't_ answer your question, then edit this question to explain why it doesn't (or ask a new question).