# How can I fix this problem: "Cannot determine size of graphic"

Tags: graphics, errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MikTex error for PNG images when trying to produce DVI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/miktex-error-for-png-images-when-trying-to-produce-dvi)

I have the following line in my tex file:

```
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{pic.png}
```

There is no error with `pdflatex`, but When I try to build it by `latex` command I get this error:

*Cannot determine size of graphic pic.png (no Bounding box).*

How can I fix this error?

**Update:**

I could fix(?) it by inserting two more values(`natwidth` and `natheight`) to `includegraphics'. Now I can build my file, however I'm not sure that it is the right way to do it.

Comment: See also [What causes latex.exe to be unable to import *.jpg, *.png, *.pdf directly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7941/)

Comment: See the linked questions above. In short: `latex` does not support PNG, JPG or PDF images. Only EPS.

Comment: @Martin: Not exactly. Dvips does not support PNG, JPG or PDF images, but dvipdfm(x) supports. In TeX Live 2010+, `latex -shell-escape` will call `extractbb` on the fly to get bounding boxes of these images. And Oberdiek's `bmpsize` package helps dvipdfm(x) determine bounding boxes of PNG and JPG images.

Comment: @Leo: indeed, there are ways around that but in principle `latex` doesn't support these format, i.e. is unable to extract their sizes by itself.