# ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Pictures/logo.png (no BoundingBox)

Tags: graphics

I have been using `MikTeX version 2.9.5105` without any trouble.
I tried to compile using `XeLaTeX` option on a file that worked perfectly without this option. I had errors. So I decided to come back to the former settings (`LaTeX+dvips+ps2pdf`)

Now, I have a problem: the simplest latex file that contains a given image outuputs me this message all the time:

```
*! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Pictures/logo.png (no BoundingBox).*
```

After trying to resolve this problem by doing what former answers to this similar question, I uninstalled `MikTeX` and reinstalled it again: the problem is always here.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What causes latex.exe to be unable to import *.jpg, *.png, *.pdf directly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7941/16967) and related: [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/16967)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: have you read my question before saying it is duplicate ?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17734/15925 help?

Comment: @begueradj: If you do not want to include a PNG file (`logo.png`) with LaTeX/dvips (`LaTeX+dvips+ps2pdf`), then clarify the question and explain, why the duplicate/related questions do not fit.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I want to use PNG files and all others image extensions.

Comment: @AndrewSwann no, I tried it before posting this question.

Comment: @begueradj: If you want PNG files with `latex`/`dvips`, then convert them to EPS and read the answers to the related questions.

Comment: I want to use the pictures in their 'natural' format, without converting them.

Comment: @begueradj: Then use a driver that can include the pictures, e.g. pdfTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you, it works ! I used the second option of `pdfLaTeX` you asked me (with the second option I mean `pdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the second option of `pdfLaTeX` you asked me (with the second option I mean `pdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex`) 
Answered by: Heiko Oberdiek  (above)