# I encountered an 'errorUnknown graphics extension: .eps.'

Tags: graphics, errors, eps

I tried to load an .eps picture, but an error occured,

> errorUnknown graphics extension: .eps.

Comment: Does it complain about `.eps` or about `.eps.` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are probably compiling your TEX document using `pdftex` (or `pdflatex`) while including an EPS image. This will not work. You need to convert the EPS to PDF (using something like the [`epstopdf` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf)), or Distiller from Adobe Acrobat.

For more information on this type of problem, read the [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-unkgrfextn) TeX FAQ entry.

Alternatively, you may switch the compiler from `pdftex` to `latex`, which accepts EPS graphic format.

---

The best way around this is to never specify the graphic extension in your `\includegraphics{...}` command, but have both EPS and PDF versions of the file available. That will ensure that the correct type is used during compilation, as the driver will make the appropriate selection.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflate