# Latex error. Unknown graphics extension: eps

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I encountered an 'errorUnknown graphics extension: .eps.'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24831/i-encountered-an-errorunknown-graphics-extension-eps)

I have the error like in the title. I found some pages on the web with a solution to this problem. They use to say that compiling should be not LaTeX->pdf but LaTeX->ps->pdf. How can it be done, or maybe there is another solution for the problem?

Comment: pdfLaTeX only accepts `.pdf`, `.png` and `.jpg` graphics. With recent TeX Live (2010, 2011) or MiKTeX (2.9) versions, automatic EPS-to-PDF conversion takes place when an `.eps` file is available. What TeX system do you use?

Comment: See also: [Why can't pdflatex print EPS figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383/why-cant-pdflatex-print-eps-figures)

Comment: don't forget to `\usepackage{graphicx}` before `\usepackage{epstopdf}`

Comment: yegor256 is absolutely right!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It seems you're using graphics in the .eps format. A relatively easy way of solving this problem is loading `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in your preamble and compiling with pdfLaTeX as usual. This will convert any .eps graphics to .pdf first, you'll see the actual .pdf files in your directory.

Comment: nice answer. helped me

Answer (score 2):

Consult the wikibook on LaTeX: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics

> Compiling with pdflatex
>   ...
>   **EPS** can be used with the help of the epstopdf package. Please see these: http://dirkraffel.com/2007/11/19/include-eps-files-in-latex