# How to insert eps files in texmaker?

Tags: graphics, eps

I am new to LaTeX. I got a problem with an eps files. When I use

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{mjo.pdf}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

I got LaTeX Error:

```
unknown graphics extension.eps se the latex manual...
```

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: you get an error about an eps extension if you use the extension .pdf ? that sounds strange.

Comment: I think you will find a solution here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29664/latex-error-unknown-graphics-extension-eps

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.