# A graphics problem where LaTeX->PS->PDF and LaTeX->PDF both fail

Tags: graphics

I have a Latex-file with some `\psplots` and `\includegraphics` commands. 
When I compile with LaTeX->PS->PDF the \psplots are okay but I get the error message

```
cannot determine the size of graphic in fig5.jpg
```

And fig5 is much to big. And also 
some characters f.E `\ding{46}` are printed not correctly.

When I compile directly Latex->PDF I only get the right size of Fig5.jpg but no drawings from the plots. The `\ding{46}` is correct.

I use the latest versions of `MikTeX`, `TexnicCenter` and `GhostScript` (I updated the today)

What is wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pstricks} 
\usepackage{pst-plot} 
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(6,6) 
\psset{xunit=30pt, yunit=3pt} 
\psgrid[Ox=0, Oy=0, xunit=1, yunit=10,subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabelcolor=white](0,0)(0,0)(6,6) 
\psaxes[Dx=1,Dy=10,linewidth=1pt,ticksize=4pt](0,0)(0,0)(6,60) \psplot[plotpoints=200, algebraic=true, linewidth=2pt]{0}{3}{3*x^2+4} 
\end{pspicture} 
\\ 
\\ 
\ding{46} 
\\ 
\includegraphics[width={\textwidth}]{fig5.jpg} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! JPG/PDF/PNG images and \psplot will not work together. Please convert the image to EPS and run LaTeX -> PS -> PDF.

Comment: Does that `\psplot` command come from »[PSTricks](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks)«? If so, try the »[auto-pst-pdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf)« package and pay special attention to the remarks in its manual regarding `-shell-escape`. If that doesn't help, please prepare a self-contained and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/21591 is helpful here.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(6,6)
    \psset{xunit=30pt, yunit=3pt}
    \psgrid[Ox=0, Oy=0, xunit=1, yunit=10,subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabelcolor=white](0,0)(0,0)(6,6)
    \psaxes[Dx=1,Dy=10,linewidth=1pt,ticksize=4pt](0,0)(0,0)(6,60)
    \psplot[plotpoints=200, algebraic=true, linewidth=2pt]{0}{3}{3*x^2+4}
\end{pspicture} \\\ding{46}
\\includegraphics[width={\textwidth}]{fig5.jpg}


\end{document}

Comment: I have found the solution. compile with xelatex->PDF and everything went alright

Thanks

Comment: Based on that comment, duping to the general 'PSTricks + PDF output' question seems best: XeLaTeX is the answer given there!