# Importing JPG files into LaTeX

Tags: graphics, import

I would like to import JPG file into my document in LaTeX. The code below works but only for EPS files, but I need JPG. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For inclusion of JPG images, you cannot use the latex compiler. You need to use pdflatex. See [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `pdflatex` to compile it, which support `jpg` images. Check out [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Compiling_with_pdflatex) for more info.

[image]

**Update:** as commented by @daleif, `MPS`, i.e. metapost eps can also be included via `pdflatex` without the need of conversion.

Comment: You're forgetting MPS, metapost eps, that can be included via pdflatex without the need of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I generally convert the `filename.eps` or `.jpg` or `.png` or whatever to PDF, rename the `filename.pdf` to `filename_converted_to.pdf` and insert `filename.eps` in the `\includegraphics` command..

It's what's done during the pdflatex compilation process.

You'll have something like that:

```
\includegraphics{./imgs/filename.jpg}
```

Comment: I cannot make sense of this answer. You convert a jpg to pdf rename it and never use that name again, then you include the eps but in the example it's a jpg? I'm confused. Plus, is this really an answer for `latex` or rather for `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Christian yes like sneak around then pull it back right there.