# pdfTeX and JPEG2000

Tags: graphics, pdftex, jpeg

In [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat), the answers indicate that that pdfLaTeX understands JPEG2000. For me it doesn't work and the above link seems to be about the only place where a `.jp2`-positive statement is made.

Could someone please clarify the matter for me?

Comment: Are you using it as `\includegraphics{file.jp2}`? What about renaming it to `.jpg`?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a useless message. Please read http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: @Heiko It is a statement of not much use, indeed. Sorry. I tried giving the file in question a `.jpg` extension. Pdftex then says, "reading JPEG image failed (no JPEG header found)", which could be expected with a file in JPEG2000 format. When I include the file by `\includegraphics{file.jb2}`, i.e., with the explicit extension, I get "readfilehdr(): reading JBIG2 image file failed: ID string missing". Could this mean there is something wrong with my file? If it means anything, Irfanview recognizes the format and displays the file correctly.

Comment: That answer was wrong; fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pdfTeX cannot handle JPEG2000 images, but LuaTeX can.

For LuaTeX `pdftex.def` can be extended to support `.jp2` as file extension for JPEG2000 files:

Workaround:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{ifpdf}
  \ifpdf
    \expandafter\ifx\csname Gin@rule@.jp2\endcsname\relax
      \DeclareGraphicsRule{.jp2}{jpg}{.jp2}{#1}
      \DeclareGraphicsRule{.JP2}{jpg}{.JP2}{#1}
      \usepackage{grfext}
      \AppendGraphicsExtensions{.jp2,.JP2}
    \fi
  \fi  
\fi
```

This adds a rule for `.jp2` (and the uppercase variant `.JP2`) and adds the extension to the search list of the supported graphics extensions.

A small test file worked for AR9.5.5/Linux, but other PDF viewers (xpdf 3.03, ghostscript 9.05, evince 3.4.0) are not able to display the image properly.

Comment: You're mixing JBIG2 and JPEG2000 images.

Comment: This doesn't help, I am afraid. The error message I now get is, "unknown type of image". Can you confirm that pdfLaTeX is able to handle JPEG2000 files?

Comment: I am confused. Does luaTeX support JPEG2000 or not?

Comment: @AlexG: I had converted a file with `image_to_j2k` to `.jp2` and LuaTeX 0.76.0 could read/include it in the output PDF file. Also the documentation of LuaTeX (4.5.8 img.types) says, that JPEG 2000 is supported.

Comment: I installed openjpeg-1.5.1, but `luatex` fails to embed a jp2 file created with `image_to_j2k`. Which openjpeg version do you use? The error is `(./test.texluatex: ../../../texk/web2c/luatexdir/image/writejp2.w:216: read_jp2_info: Assertion 'hdr.tbox==0x6A502020' failed.`

Comment: @AlexG: I had used openjpeg-1.5.0 and LuaTeX 0.76.0, the error comes from LuaTeX, thus can you make a bug report including the image that triggers the error?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to convert j2 to jpg by opening it in GIMP (which will take a while and throw a message about converting to sRGB), then export to jpg (or whatever else)