# How to convert the latex file into postscript file

Tags: graphics, eps, dvips, postscript, ps

I have faced one problem. Actually, I'm working on `IEEE` paper, and they said that I have to convert my `.tex` files into postscript file

How can I get postscript file? I'm working with WinEdt 8.0 version

Should I convert first my `.jpg` figures into `.eps` format by using Photoshop, or it is not necessary step?

For figures, I use the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, angle=0]{Files/xxx.jpg}
    \caption[xxx xxxxxx xxxxx.]{xxx xxxxxx xxxxx.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Everything work perfect with me .. I can get `.pdf` file .. But `.ps` file still I don't how to find it

Comment: You need to compile using `latex` (not `pdflatex`). Your images have to converted to .ps or .eps using a tool like `Imagemagik`. You'll get a DVI file which can be converted using `dvips`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't know if it would work but you *can* convert the pdf file to ps. However, that may not be what they want. (I do this and then convert back to pdf as some journal systems won't accept pdf output directly from pdfLaTeX and some printers don't like it either.) On GNU/Linux, you can use `pdf2ps` or `pdftops` for this. Not sure about Windows, though.

Comment: @cfr That is a good idea, but chances are high that the journal wants the sources (tex and pictures) for further processing (converting xml and back).

Comment: @Johannes_B Indeed. That's why I said that that may not be what they want. I've only used it to work around things which didn't like the particular variety of PDF produced by pdfTeX.

Comment: I think you _must_ to convert all your jpg files to ps, Photoshop could be one possibility, [Imagemagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) is better in my experience.

Comment: @Aradnix: `eps`, please. `epstopdf` should work.

Comment: See [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".