# Specific format for inserting a picture

Tags: graphics

I'm preparing a paper. Its Latex template is provided. I don't understand the following quote

> We suggest that you use a text box to insert a graphic (which is
>   ideally a 300 dpi TIFF or EPS file, with all fonts embedded) because,
>   in an document, this method is somewhat more stable than directly
>   inserting a picture.

I know how to insert a picture using `figure` but what do they exactly want?

---

Edit:

I found this piece of code in the template

```
   \begin{figure}[thpb]
      \centering
      \framebox{\parbox{3in}{We suggest that you use a text box to insert a graphic (which is ideally a 300 dpi TIFF or EPS file, with all fonts embedded) because, in an document, this method is somewhat more stable than directly inserting a picture.
}}
      \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{figurefile}
      \caption{Inductance of oscillation winding on amorphous
       magnetic core versus DC bias magnetic field}
      \label{figurelabel}
   \end{figure}
```

The picture goes out of the box's frame. So what is the point of this box then?

Comment: There is no support for TIFF inclusion in TeX, so it seems like these instructions are more geared towards MS Word (which allow for the insertion of a text box).

Comment: They tell you that the method you know using the `figure`environment you know to use, isn't stable for the production method of that Journal. They find better, more stable for their workflow to insert your images in the way they suggest: inside a text box. And the original file should be TIFF or EPS with at least 300 dpi for good printed resolution.

Comment: I think you should ask to your editor for an example of that suggestion. Also because the highlight of @Werner

Comment: @Aradnix But what would that mean in LaTeX? Since TIFF is not an option at all and it is at least unclear what they mean about putting a graphic in a 'text box'.

Comment: @cfr Sincerelly I don't know, that's why CroCo should ask the editor or the printer about it.

Comment: I *think* they mean that they want you to put a text box in your document *instead* of including the image. Then you provide the graphic *separately* as a TIFF or EPS file. The text box is just a 'placeholder' indicating where the figure should go and which figure should go there. The point about embedding fonts is then just that these need to be fully embedded into the file containing the graphic.

Comment: See [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/5764)

Comment: @Werner I'm not sure that is relevant. The issue here is what the journal has requested and not what can or cannot be included by latex or pdflatex. Integrating them into the document is not the author's problem.

Comment: I found some code in the template but it doesn't work. the picture goes out of the frame. Please see the modification.

Comment: Email them. That doesn't make any sense. Either they know very little about LaTeX or they know very little about English or both. You *cannot* insert a TIFF there. You could, obviously, make an image fit the box. But I don't see why they would want all images to be 3" or whatever. Notice, though, that they don't actually put the graphic in the box. The `\includegraphics` command is outside the scope of `\framebox` and `\parbox`.

Comment: @cfr, how to fit the picture in the box? I'm using two columns style and the picture always goes out of the page unless I change its width and height. This is IEEE style though.

Comment: Well, yes. Obviously you can only fit it in the box by scaling it. But I think you should ask them for an example or to clarify their instructions.

Comment: When googling the passage you quote, I find various sources where the text reads *We suggest that you use a text box to insert a graphic (which is ideally a 300 dpi TIFF or EPS file, with all fonts embedded) because, in an **Word** document, this method is somewhat more stable than directly inserting a picture*. Emphasis mine. Hence, it would appear as @Werner suggested that this was geared towards MSWord, perhaps they just naively used the same instructions for the LaTeX template, or forgot to edit the text.