# How to embed graphics formats

Tags: graphics, format-files

Is it possible to include .x3d, .dae, .pov, .dxf, or .wmf grapics into tex-syntax in order to create a pdf file?

Comment: The answer here is going to be short: 'no'. I assume you've seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat?

Comment: It might be possible to convert some of them to U3D or PRC, so that the `media9` package can read them.