# pdflatex cannot find PDF

Tags: graphics, errors, sweave

I am using Sweave (in Emacs) to generate a report.  I can compile the `.tex` file just fine.  There are images (PDFs) that I generate (I have `graphicx` included in my `\usepackage{}`; I am not dealing with issues coming from LaTeX looking for EPS files) in my code.  When I go to run `pdflatex` on my resulting `*.tex` file, I get the error below. The picture in question (normalization_analysis-002) is in the same folder as my `*.tex` file.  Moreover, I get this error whether I attempt to compile through Emacs or via the command line; in Emacs and command line my working directory is the same directory as where the `*.tex` file is located.  Finally, this is the first time this problem has occurred, despite using Emacs + Sweave for some months now on the same computer system for a variety of projects.   What is happening?

I should point out that recompiling other files on the same system works.  I cannot generate a reproducible error b/c the data I am using is not public yet, so I am asking instead for advice about how to troubleshoot this issue.

The log is available [here](http://pastebin.com/7yvKwNcr)

```
! LaTeX Error: File `normalization_analysis-002' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.30 \includegraphics{normalization_analysis-002}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.30 \includegraphics{normalization_analysis-002}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on normalization_analysis.log.
```

Per a comment from @David Carlisle, adding `.pdf` to the argument to `\includegraphic{}` yields the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `normalization_analysis-002.pdf' not found on input line 86
.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `normalization\unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \h
skip \z@skip \T1\textunderscore \discretionary {-}{}{}\penalty \@M \hskip \z@sk
ip analysis-002.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.86 ...degraphics{normalization_analysis-002.pdf}
```

Comment: You can't include EPS files directly into a pdfLaTeX document. See [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/5764) If the image is EPS, convert it to PDF and try again.

Comment: It's not EPS. It's Pdf.

Comment: In the question text, the file name has two hyphens, in the `.log` excerpt the first hyphen is an underscore.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's a typo on my part. The quote is correct as it is auto generated by Sweave

Comment: what is the full name of the image file?

Comment: /home/USER/Copy/DIR/normalization_analysis-002.pdf.  Capitalized words are changed for privacy reasons.

Comment: without seeing a real example or the log have to guess so guesses are: graphics has been passed the wrong option (eg `[dvips]` would be bad) or the file isn't readable due to permissions or being locked by another process or something, or the current working directory pr pdflatex isn't where you expected so effectively the pdf file isn't there or something I can't guess:-)

Comment: try putting .pdf explicitly at the end of the \includegraphics argument. that forces a different code path that would rule out some of the guesses in the comment above.

Comment: I tried your most recent suggestion (post updated).  Also, permissions/use issues are not applicable - permissions are what they should be, no other programs are using the PDF.  Also, from command line, I call within *.tex directory.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Heiko has answered this question.  Thank you for your input

Comment: @learner well you made it easy for him with that log fragment:-)

Comment: @learner macros are expanded in the file name but you have `_` defined to a macro to have an effect on typesetting so latex was looking for a file with the name `normalization\unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \h
skip \z@skip \T1\textunderscore \discretionary {-}{}{}\penalty \@M \hskip \z@sk
ip analysis-002.pdf`

Comment: Ah.  Yikes.  Is this in general a behavior of latex?  Or do I have somewhat unusual system settings?

Comment: expanding macros is a general behaviour (tex is a macro expansion language:-) normally `_` is not expandable, it would just write as itself but normally it is a math only character for subscripts `x_2` looks like you have a non standard definition of _ so that it makes a _ in text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.log` excerpt of the updated question shows that the underscore is an active character, which is expanded, when the `graphics` package with driver `pdftex.def` looks for the file. Here you can deactivate the underscore token with `\string`:

```
\includegraphics{normalization\string_analysis-002}
```

The `.log` file shows that the underscore is made active by package `underscore`.

Active characters act like commands or macros. When the `graphics` package looks for the image file name, then it also expands macros (that allows, that parts of the file name can be specified by macros). Package `underscore` defines `_` as active character. As result the underscore can be directly used to get an underscore without the need to use the backslash. The expansion result of the active `_` gives the stuff, you can see in the `.log` file:

```
"\unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip \T1\textunderscore \discretionary {-}{}{}\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip "
```

Pretty surely your system does not contain a file name with such a funny name inside.

Package `underscore` takes some precaution for the active underscore by supporting `babel`'s mechanism for its shorthand characters, but package `graphics` does not support babel shorthands.

The command `\string` converts the next token to its character representation with non-active characters (category code 12 and the space has category code 10). Thus the active `_` becomes an inactive underscore character token.

Comment: Wow.  Good catch.  Would you mind writing up a bit of explanation about why that was a problem?  I'd like to understand, and perhaps others will have this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

in windows O.S:
go to start --> Miktex --> MikteX console
then change to administartor mode
just select update center and then update your program packages