# Simple includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I'm using Texmaker 4.4.1, When I compile with LaTex it returns an error of file "test" not found, when I compile it with PDFLaTex, it works fine. test is a pdf file in the directory of my .tex file.
I use this simple command:

```
\includegraphics{test}
```

I have all the necessary packages and the file compiles with PDFLaTeX.
I already checked: packages, filename, directory, resetting texmaker settings, restarting, Capital letters everything works for PDFLatex but not for Latex.
Anyway, what is the difference between compiling with LaTeX and PDFLaTeX?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072 perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX uses TeX to compile. Or, these days, it uses pdfTeX but in TeX mode i.e. it behaves like TeX. This is the current version of the original engine. It doesn't know anything about PDF. It produces a DVI file which you can either view using a capable viewer or convert to PS, PDF or other format.

pdfLaTeX uses pdfTeX to compile. That is, it uses pdfTeX in pdfTeX mode. This is a newer engine. It compiles to PDF directly - no conversion from DVI is required. It knows (unsurprisingly) all about PDF.

More generally, if you use the TeX engine, any graphics must be EPS. If you use pdfTeX, you can use PDF directly without conversion. Generally, pdfTeX can use a wider range of graphics formats without need for conversion. (Though it cannot use EPS without conversion.)

So if the image is PDF, TeX will complain when you try to include it. Either use pdfLaTeX rather than LaTeX or convert the image to EPS.