# bitmap inclusion with latex->dvi failing

Tags: graphics, dvi, bitmap

The MWE below works fine for me on my (Mac) laptop compiling with `latex` (to dvi), and the bitmap image is included just fine.

My friend has both a Mac laptop and a Mac desktop, with a recent TeXLive installation on both. Running `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` just leaves a big blank space where the bitmap should be. Compiling with `xelatex` makes the image appear just fine for her in the resulting pdf, but what could be going on with `latex` failing to include the bitmap?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{testpic.bmp}}
\end{document}
```

Here is her log file from a TeXShop-induced "TeX and DVI" mode run:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=latex 2015.7.27)  27 JUL 2015 13:02
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**bmp_testpic.tex
(./bmp_testpic.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 94.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2014/10/14 v3.0j Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(./bmp_testpic.aux)
\openout1 = `bmp_testpic.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
File: testpic.bmp Graphic file (type bmp)
 <testpic.bmp> [1

] (./bmp_testpic.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 513 strings out of 493094
 6255 string characters out of 6135015
 57530 words of memory out of 5000000
 4063 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,5n,19p,188b,109s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on bmp_testpic.dvi (1 page, 336 bytes).
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat

Comment: @JosephWright Why does the bitmap inclusion work for me on my machine with `latex mwe.tex`, but not for her on hers with the same command? I've always thought bmp was supported with tex->dvi->ps->pdf. But this answer omits bmp; was I wrong or is that new?

Comment: Log files please :-)

Comment: Also, do you have a `.bb` file (bitmaps can be allowed by `latex` if some bounding box data is given).

Comment: @JosephWright I added the log. I don't see a `.bb` file on either my system (where it works) or hers (where it doesn't).

Comment: OK, I'd go for adding `\listfiles` on both systems and getting the file version logs. I'm wondering about `dvips.def`: I have a feeling Heiko Oberdiek added some cleverness at some point for bitmaps.

Comment: Are you compiling with shell escape enabled?