# png, jpeg, etc not being found

Tags: miktex, installing, texmaker

I just did a clean install of windows 10, and I'm trying to get latex up and running again.

I just installed the basic MikTex 2.9 package and TexMaker.  I gave MikTex the authority to install packages on the fly without asking.

The first problem that I have run into is that my figures are no longer compiling.

The code:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}


\begin{figure}[h!] 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{PercentageGraph} 
\caption{Accuracy in visual degrees versus how much of the data
    can be expected to fall within that radius. } 
\end{figure}
```

PercentageGraph.png is in the same directory as all my other documents.

The error that latex reports:

```
!LaTeX Error: File `PercentageGraph' not found.  
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.  
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.326 ...hics[width=\columnwidth]{PercentageGraph}  
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:  
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps  
Try typing <return> to proceed.  
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
```

Am I reading that correctly that it is no longer searching for png, jpeg, pdf, etc?  How do I put those file extensions back into the search criteria for images?

Comment: You're probably compiling with LaTeX (shortcut F2) instead of pdfLaTeX (shortcut F6). When compiling in DVI-mode, i.e. with `latex`, only EPS-images are allowed, while with `pdflatex` you can use PNG, JPG or  PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You were using `latex` to generate a document (shortcut F2 in Texmaker), and in that case you can only include EPS files. To be able to include JPEG and PNG image you need to use `pdflatex` (shortcut F6). `lualatex` and `xelatex` can also handle JPEG and PNG.

See also [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat)