# LaTeX Error: File `...' not found

Tags: graphics, sharelatex

There are 13 files that are included in images under the `.tex`, but this is a typical error message I get for the first one, which is the same error for all with different file names of course, all of them are a `.jpg` file and worked earlier,

```
`LaTeX Error: File `uob' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.40 ...graphics[width=0.4\textwidth, center]{uob}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.`
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Comment: I suspect you're compiling with `latex` instead of `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be compiling your document using LaTeX, while [`.jpg` files can only be included under pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/5764). Change your compiler:

[image]