# How to include eps figure MiKTeX 2.9, pdfLaTeX, shared Windows computer

Tags: graphics, pdftex, miktex, eps

I've finally managed to get my file to compile, but the image I want to include isn't showing up. I get a big bit of blank space.

Without all the actual text stuff going on, this is what I've got:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{Im1.eps}
        \end{center}
        \caption{\it Dots represent drug concentration equally distributed about the body. \label{boostFig} }
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Caption shows up fine, and there's a wondering empty gap above it where I presume the image should go. The file Im1.eps is saved in the same folder as the .tex file, but there's not much more I can do about file paths because the only place this software is available is my much restricted University computers.

Any idea where my image is, if not in my document?

(If we can't answer that, can someone confirm how you turn a .png to an .eps then on Windows? Or how you include a .png file without the hoohah of turning to .eps?)

Comment: Check in the log-file if the call to epstopdf worked. Beside this: If you have a png, use it directly. This will work fine with pdflatex.

Comment: If you have a subdirectory for auxiliary files, try putting the .eps file into this subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Please see [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1075).