# TeXnicCenter Compiling problems with MikTeX 2.9 Windows 7

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm installing Latex, due to PC format operation. I've installed AcrobatPro 11; MiKTeX 2.9; and TeXnicCenter (TXCSetup_2.02Stable_Win32); Ghostscript 9.11win32; gsview5.0

I usually compile like this LaTeX=>DVI=>PDF. But now it hangs on! I have to close the TXC and restart.

So now I'm using LaTeX=>PDF. But I'm still having problems with the package `texdraw`. The package is installed correctly, but the problem arises when introducing the command.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centertexdraw{
    \drawdim cm
    \arrowheadtype t:F
    \move(0 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (2 -1.2){$P_1$}
    \move(2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (4 -1.2){$P_2$} 
    \move(4 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05  \lpatt(0.067 0.1)\rlvec (2 0) \lpatt()\fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (6 -1.2){$P_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 0) \textref h:C v:T \htext (0 -.2){$O$}
    \move (2 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (2 -.2){$\underline{I_1}$}
    \move (4 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (4 -.2){$\underline{I_2}$}
    \move (6 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (6 -.2){$\underline{I_\textnormal{n}}$}
    \move (.5 0) \lvec (.6 .1)      \move (.5 0) \lvec (.4 -.1) 
    \move (.6 0) \lvec (.7 .1)      \move (.6 0) \lvec (.5 -.1)
    \move (0 0) \rlvec (0 .6) \move (2 0) \lvec (2 .6) \move (1 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (1 0.1){$L_1$}
    \move (0 0.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (2 0.5)
    \move (0 0.5) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (4 0) \lvec (4 1.2) \move (3 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (3 0.6){$L_2$}
    \move (0 1)         \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (4 1)
    \move (0 1) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (6 0) \lvec (6 1.6) \move (5 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (5 1.1){$L_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 1.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (6 1.5)
    \move (0 2) \move (0 -2) %Para hacer sitio
    }       
\caption{Monofásica. Esquema unifilar.}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centertexdraw{
    \drawdim cm
    \arrowheadtype t:F
    \move(0 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (2 -1.2){$P_1$}
    \move(2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (4 -1.2){$P_2$} 
    \move(4 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05  \lpatt(0.067 0.1)\rlvec (2 0) \lpatt()\fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (6 -1.2){$P_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 0) \textref h:C v:T \htext (0 -.2){$O$}
    \move (2 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (2 -.2){$\underline{I_1}$}
    \move (4 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (4 -.2){$\underline{I_2}$}
    \move (6 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (6 -.2){$\underline{I_\textnormal{n}}$}
    \move (.5 0) \lvec (.6 .1)      \move (.5 0) \lvec (.4 -.1) 
    \move (.6 0) \lvec (.7 .1)      \move (.6 0) \lvec (.5 -.1)
    \move (.7 0) \lvec (.8 .1)      \move (.7 0) \lvec (.6 -.1)
    \move (.8 0) \lvec (.9 .1)      \move (.8 0) \lvec (.7 -.1)     
    \move (0 0) \rlvec (0 .6) \move (2 0) \lvec (2 .6) \move (1 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (1 0.1){$L_1$}
    \move (0 0.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (2 0.5)
    \move (0 0.5) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (4 0) \lvec (4 1.2) \move (3 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (3 0.6){$L_2$}
    \move (0 1)         \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (4 1)
    \move (0 1) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (6 0) \lvec (6 1.6) \move (5 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (5 1.1){$L_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 1.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (6 1.5)
    \move (0 2) \move (0 -2) %Para hacer sitio
    }   
\caption{Trifásica. Esquema unifilar.}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The bug points on the bracket that closes the sentence `$\centertexdraw{   }$`

The error log indicates the following:

> ```
> pdflatex> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps1
> ```

If anyone knows the solution... thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable! Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: See also [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072)

Comment: \setcounter{chapter}{0}

\begin{document} 

\sloppy

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to compile from LaTeX=>DVI=>PS=>PDF. LaTeX=>PDF always gives the same error.
I use in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[dvips,pdf,xcolor,10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{texdraw}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centertexdraw{
    \drawdim cm
    \arrowheadtype t:F
    \move(0 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (2 -1.2){$P_1$}
    \move(2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (4 -1.2){$P_2$} 
    \move(4 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05  \lpatt(0.067 0.1)\rlvec (2 0) \lpatt()\fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (6 -1.2){$P_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 0) \textref h:C v:T \htext (0 -.2){$O$}
    \move (2 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (2 -.2){$\underline{I_1}$}
    \move (4 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (4 -.2){$\underline{I_2}$}
    \move (6 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (6 -.2){$\underline{I_\textnormal{n}}$}
    \move (.5 0) \lvec (.6 .1)      \move (.5 0) \lvec (.4 -.1) 
    \move (.6 0) \lvec (.7 .1)      \move (.6 0) \lvec (.5 -.1)
    \move (0 0) \rlvec (0 .6) \move (2 0) \lvec (2 .6) \move (1 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (1 0.1){$L_1$}
    \move (0 0.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (2 0.5)
    \move (0 0.5) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (4 0) \lvec (4 1.2) \move (3 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (3 0.6){$L_2$}
    \move (0 1)         \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (4 1)
    \move (0 1) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (6 0) \lvec (6 1.6) \move (5 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (5 1.1){$L_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 1.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (6 1.5)
    \move (0 2) \move (0 -2) %Para hacer sitio
    }       
\caption{Monofásica. Esquema unifilar.}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centertexdraw{
    \drawdim cm
    \arrowheadtype t:F
    \move(0 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (2 -1.2){$P_1$}
    \move(2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \rlvec (2 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (4 -1.2){$P_2$} 
    \move(4 0) \fcir f:0 r:0.05  \lpatt(0.067 0.1)\rlvec (2 0) \lpatt()\fcir f:0 r:0.05 \ravec (0 -1) \textref h:C v:T \htext (6 -1.2){$P_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 0) \textref h:C v:T \htext (0 -.2){$O$}
    \move (2 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (2 -.2){$\underline{I_1}$}
    \move (4 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (4 -.2){$\underline{I_2}$}
    \move (6 0) \textref h:L v:T \htext (6 -.2){$\underline{I_\textnormal{n}}$}
    \move (.5 0) \lvec (.6 .1)      \move (.5 0) \lvec (.4 -.1) 
    \move (.6 0) \lvec (.7 .1)      \move (.6 0) \lvec (.5 -.1)
    \move (.7 0) \lvec (.8 .1)      \move (.7 0) \lvec (.6 -.1)
    \move (.8 0) \lvec (.9 .1)      \move (.8 0) \lvec (.7 -.1)     
    \move (0 0) \rlvec (0 .6) \move (2 0) \lvec (2 .6) \move (1 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (1 0.1){$L_1$}
    \move (0 0.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (2 0.5)
    \move (0 0.5) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (4 0) \lvec (4 1.2) \move (3 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (3 0.6){$L_2$}
    \move (0 1)         \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (4 1)
    \move (0 1) \rlvec (0 0.6) \move (6 0) \lvec (6 1.6) \move (5 0) \textref h:C v:B \htext (5 1.1){$L_\textnormal{n}$}
    \move (0 1.5)       \arrowheadtype t:V \avec (6 1.5)
    \move (0 2) \move (0 -2) %Para hacer sitio
    }   
\caption{Trifásica. Esquema unifilar.}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]