# Including PNG image produces error with latex+dvips+ps2pdf

Tags: ps2pdf

I'm compiling the following file `hello.tex`, which contains a picture:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5cm, natwidth=1079, natheight=377]{x.png} 
\end{document}
```

This produces the correct output with `xelatex hello.tex`. However, for various reasons I need to use latex+dvips+ps2pdf:

```
latex hello.tex
dvips hello.dvi
ps2pdf hello.ps
```

However, the last step produces an error:

```
C:\Users\Bai\Desktop>ps2pdf hello.ps
Error: /syntaxerror in (binary token, type=137)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1967   1   3   %oparray_pop   1966   1   3   %oparray_pop   1950   1   3   %oparray_pop   1836   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1197/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--   --dict:102/300(L)--   --dict:43/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 22237
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat: you can't use `.png` with `dvips`, you'll need to convert to EPS.

Comment: Why don't you comîle with `pdflatex`? It understands the .png and .jpeg formats natively.

Comment: Converting to EPS fixed it, thanks! I can't use pdflatex or xelatex because another package in my project only supports the latex+dvips+ps2pdf workflow.