# how to include a .xcf gimp file in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Gimp usually saves files with `.xcf` extension and I have experienced loss of quality by using "export" instead of "save".

I would like to know if there is a standard way to include an .xcf file in a tikzpicture.

By the way, I tried with

```
  \node at (0,0){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{mypic.xcf}}
```

but this results in the error

```
Cannot determine size of graphic in flymoonCb.xcf (no BoundingBox).
```

Comment: I doubt TeX can read `.xcf`s. Does the quality also decrease drastically if you export the image as `.jpg` with higher quality settings,`.png` or `.pdf` (depending on the type of image one of the formats might be more appropriate than the others). Very relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/35864

Comment: as far as I can determine no one has ever written an .xcf direct importer for TeX dvi or eps There is a gimp xcf to svg plugin and dozens of .xcf to "other" online converters however the best quality solution is probably  to export to png in bitmap cases or use ghostscript/inkscape processing to eps or build pdfs with either ps or svg vectors which can be \included

Comment: Would be useful to have still.

Answer (score 3):

### Short Answer

You **can not** directly use the XCF file format in LaTeX, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072) for an overview of supported formats.

I assume that you just exported the GIMP picture "wrong", I have good experience with PDF format or PNG format, or even JPEG format (given a good enough resolution).

### Longer Answer (Copied From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCF_(file_format)))

> XCF, short for eXperimental Computing Facility,[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCF_(file_format)) is the **native image**
> **format of the GIMP image-editing program**. It saves all of the data the
> program handles related to the image, including, among others, each
> layer, the current selection, channels, transparency, paths and
> guides.
>
> [...]
>
> Despite some use in other programs [...], the **use of XCF as a data interchange format is** **not
> recommended by the developers** of GIMP, since the format reflects
> **GIMP's internal data structures** and there may be minor format changes
> in future versions. Instead, a collaborative effort between the
> developers of GIMP and Krita is underway to design a standardised
> raster file format called OpenRaster (modelled on the OpenDocument
> format) for future use in both applications, and likely in others
> also.