# Generate DVI file from valid TEX with pdflatex returns error for images

Tags: pdftex, includegraphics, dvi

I can render PDF using `pdflatex` normally, I used Makefile like this:

```
all:
    pdflatex $(PAPER).tex
    bibtex $(PAPER)
    pdflatex $(PAPER).tex
    pdflatex $(PAPER).tex
```

This renders PDF with no problems.
However, if I want to generate DVI file by providing `--output-format dvi` option on the command line, it fails on the first `\includegraphics` statement saying that my illustration was not found (I use PDF vector files and don't include ".pdf" extension with file name in `\includegraphics`).

Does it mean I have to go over the whole document and add ".pdf" in every `\includegraphics` I have?

**UPDATE**

When added ".pdf", I get this error:

```
LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in video-ip.pdf (no BoundingBox).
```

Comment: You cannot embed PDF graphics in DVI files, as far as I know, you have to use PostScript graphics (EPS)

Comment: Inputs need to be EPS (with imbedded bounding box) or possibly some other formats if the bb entry is supplied, simplest is to use some form of PDF2EPS

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat).

Comment: why use `pdflatex --output-format=dvi` rather than `latex` ?

Comment: @siracusa you can't embed any filetype really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DVI files do not include graphics at all, just a reference to the filename, so whether you can then process the referenced PDF file depends on the driver you use. By default latex assumes `dvips` will be used, that can not include PDF files however you can convert all your PDF  to EPS. Alternatively you can use a driver such as `dvipdfmx` which can include pdF, in which case, use the `dvipdfmx` option to `graphicx` so it inserts appropriate `\special` in to the DVI file.