# Why are my images blurry in pdflatex?

Tags: beamer, graphics, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My pixel perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex)

I am currently creating a presentation using `beamer`. For this I am taking screenshots, and then I use Gimp to scale them appropriately, so that I can import them in LaTeX without scaling:

```
\includegraphics{someimage}
```

The images are in PNG format. The problem is, even though the images appear very clear and sharp in Gimp, they always end up blurry in the PDF. Can someone explain why that is?

Comment: Might be related: [My pixel perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex)

Comment: Try out [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex/10978#10978) to disable "Smooth images" in Acrobat Reader, if you are using it.

Comment: @Martin: I am using Apple's Preview, but it has such an option too, and it does the trick. Thanks! You can either post this as an answer so I can accept it, or just close it as duplicate.