# Switch off anti-aliasing in bitmaps

Tags: graphics, pdftex, aliasing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My pixel perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex)

When including a small bitmap scaled to a larger size: how can I disable anti-aliasing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=15]{sqares.png}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output with anti-aliased sqares]

with this image:

[image: squares.png]

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps you, but the question is quite similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex

Comment: I found another question like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21732/deactivating-anti-aliasing-when-typesetting-qr-code by now, I'm sure that you will have to turn it off in the reader, not in LaTeX.

Comment: @Dave oh yes, this is viewer-dependent :( Acrobat Reader works fine, Mac Preview (Skim) is blurry.

Comment: Can be closed as duplicate or I'll delete it. Thanks @Dave!

Comment: Actually there is a flag in the PDF spec, but it is ignored by some PDF viewer applications :( (cf. "Image Interpolation")