# Print screen img - png/eps loses quality with no scaling

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, png

I am trying to include image to LaTeX, but I loose quality.

It is a print-screen with image and little bit of text and it looks awful after the conversion to PDF.

I guess that DPI of the image is 90, it was taken in windows 8 with it's snipping tool.

I can convert the image with no visual cost to EPS but not PDF.

ANY suggestions, please ?

EDIT: it almost looks like the image is rescaled to 99.99%

I have tried to use pdflatex, ps2pdf, dvipdfm... nothing helped

Comment: Related: [My pixel perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex)

Comment: Inside your pdf viewer, zoom to see the image at pixel level. Compare it to the same action inside a bitmap editor. They should look the same. When you don't zoom the image, the viewer has to reduce the number of pixels shown, to adapt the image to the visible size. Depending on the algorithm it uses, the result can be awful, but it is only a presentation issue. The image still is (should be) OK inside the pdf, and should print OK.

Comment: @JLDiaz: Some PDF viewers smooth images even when you're zooming past the pixel level (due to an option called "Smooth Images" in Acrobat that's enabled by default), so they won't look the same as in a bitmap editor. But yes, the underlying image is unaffected by this and should print okay.