# Disable anti-aliasing in ps2pdf

Tags: eps, ps2pdf

I have generated the EPS files my self. In the EPS files, I have set the `\interpolate false` option. I include them in the LaTeX source with `includegraphics` within TikZ (because I want several of them positioned nicely close to each other.)

Then I run the standard set of steps:

```
latex src.tex
dvips -Ppdf src.dvi
ps2pdf src.ps
```

In a text editor, I see that the PostScript source file, has preserved the full EPS file text. Even my comments in it (as it should). So the `\interpolate false` line has also remained. When I open the PostScript source with Evince (the GNOME pdf viewer), indeed there is no interpolation. Just for a check, with the editor I set `\interpolate true` and re-opened the PostScript file and confirmed that indeed now Evince interpolates the image. This shows that atleast Evince understands this option.

But when I open the `src.pdf` file that was output from ps2pdf. I see that the output is interpolated (anti-aliased) in any case! I also opened the PDF file with a text editor and found that only the most basic parameters of the EPS image have remained (like width or height). `\interpolate false` had been removed.

From the results above, I see that the problem is not in `includegraphics` or any of the LaTeX steps or even my pdf viewer. It is in ps2pdf.

In its [documentation](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm), it seems to have `AntiAliasColorImages`, `AntiAliasGrayImages` and `AntiAliasMonoImages`, but then in the following it says:

```
(note 0) This parameter can be set and queried, but currently has no effect.
```

So when I run the following command, there is no difference:

```
ps2pdf -dAntiAliasGrayImages=false -dAntiAliasMonoImages=false src.ps
```

I wanted to see if there is any way I can solve the issue. It is very important for me that anti-aliasing does not occur in the PDF file.

Comment: This seems to me to be off-topic, but I'm not sure. It doesn't really have anything to do with TeX, as you say. `ps2pdf` is part of ghostscript. Basically, it sounds in any case as though this is just a known limitation of the software. You could file a feature request, but I can't think of much else you can do unless you want to work on a patch yourself.

Comment: You are right! The reason I posted it here was this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex . It claims that the problem lies in the PDF viewer. But the case above shows that it doesn't. Am I correct? I was assuming people who use TeX also use ps2pdf a lot also and must have experience in it.

Comment: I thought that maybe adding a `/interpolate false` line in the PDF file might fix the problem. So I asked this question in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873726/edit-non-binary-strings-in-a-binary-file . I will also try to contact the Ghostscript maintainers and suggest a feature request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value for the key `/Interpolate` in the image dictionary of the PDF file is `false`, see [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), section [8.9.5.3 Image Interpolation](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Therefore adding `/Interpolate false` only makes the default explicit. Likely, the anti-aliasing is done by the PDF viewer and it should be turned off there.

Notice also the note that comes with the description for `/Interpolate`:

> A conforming Reader may choose to not implement this feature of PDF,
>   or may use any specific implementation of interpolation that it
>   wishes.

### Test of `/Interpolate`

The driver `pdftex.def` for package `graphics` supports the boolean key `interpolate`, which maps its setting to the key `/Interpolate` in the image dictionary. The default (false) and the enabled key show the expected results with this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ9k7.png) in AR9 or xpdf 3.03 or evince 3.4.0:

```
\documentclass{article}        
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{uJ9k7.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth, interpolate]{uJ9k7.png}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. It seems to work for pdflatex and PNG. But when I apply it to a similar EPS file (with latex), it says: `! Package keyval Error: interpolate undefined.` refereing the second last line in the MWE. But this is another issue and your answer clearly resolved my question. Thank you.

Comment: @makhlaghi dvips does not support such a key, the `\special`, which is written to the PDF file does not support keys for additional features like interpolate.